# Why I always get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u " from Chrome?

Tags: javascript, json

I have spent a whole day on this, googling and searching for answers but still could not figure out.

My code is a bit long and it works well in Firefox but gets  "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u " from Chrome.

Can anyone points me out where I am wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
// when the page loads, list all the current contacts
$(document).ready(function(){

    // check if localStorage database exists
    if(!localStorage.getItem("customerDatabase")){

        // define a JSON object to hold all current address
        var contacts = {
            "users":[
                {
                    "id":"1",
                    "name":"dennis",
                    "email":"dennisboys@gmail.com"
                },
                {
                    "id":"2",
                    "name":"zoe",
                    "email":"zoeisfemale@gmail.com"             
                }
            ]   
        } // end of contacts JSON object

        // stringify the object 
        var stringObject = JSON.stringify(contacts);                

        // store it into localStorage database
        var storedDatabase = localStorage.setItem("customerDatabase", stringObject);                                            

    } else {
        // list all customers upon page loads
        listJSONCustomers();        
    }   

    // list all current contacts from JSON object in localStorage
    function listJSONCustomers(){

      var displayHTML = "";
      var i;

      // get the data from localStorage
      var storedDatabase = localStorage.getItem("customerDatabase");

      // parse the data from string to JSON object
      var parseObject = JSON.parse(storedDatabase); 

      // access the users key of the JSON object
      var userObject = parseObject.users;

      // get the length of the object (how many customers the database has)
      var contactsLength = userObject.length;     

      for(i=0; i<contactsLength; i++){
          var trElement = '<tr id="address' + (i+1) + '">';
          var tdId = '<td id="id' + (i+1) + '">' + userObject[i].id + '</td>';
          var tdName = '<td id="name' + (i+1) + '">' + userObject[i].name + '</td>';
          var tdEmail = '<td id="email' + (i+1) + '">' + userObject[i].email + '</td>';
          var tdButton = '<td id="button"><button id="editButton' + userObject[i].id + '">Edit</button> | <button id="deleteButton' + userObject[i].id + '">Delete</button></td>';

          displayHTML += trElement + tdId + tdName + tdEmail + tdButton + '</tr>';
      }     

      $('#address_list').html(displayHTML);           
    }       

    // add customer to database  
    $('#saveCustomer').click(function(){

       if( $('#customerName').val() !== "" && $('#customerEmail').val() !== "" ){

           var customerName = $('#customerName').val();
           var customerEmail = $('#customerEmail').val();

           // get the data from localStorage
           var storedDatabase = localStorage.getItem("customerDatabase");

           // parse the data from string to JSON object
           var parseObject = JSON.parse(storedDatabase);    

           // access the users key of the JSON object
           var userObject = parseObject.users;     

           // get the new entry
           var newCustomerObject = {
                                  "id": userObject.length + 1,
                                  "name": customerName,
                                  "email": customerEmail
                                  };

           // push the new entry into the object                                                            
           userObject.push(newCustomerObject);

           // convert the object into string for localStorage
           var stringObject = JSON.stringify(parseObject);         

           // store the JSON object into localStorage
           var storedDatabase = localStorage.setItem("customerDatabase", stringObject);

           // list all customes again every time a database receives a new entry
           listJSONCustomers();     

       } else {
          alert("Please enter customer's name and email.");  
       }

    }); // end of $('#saveCustomer').click();


});
```

Comment: i don't get that error in chrome if i copy and past this code. are you sure that the error belongs to this file, and not to e.g. an extension?

Comment: Maybe you have something corrupt saved in your local storage from earlier? If you print the string before calling `parse()`, does it look correct? Based on the error, the localstorage value doesn't have quotes around your `"users" key.

Comment: @loganfsmyth, I printed the string before calling parse(), Firefox returns a nice string but Chrome returns 'undefined'. But how come is that?

Comment: @Dennisboys That means that you have at some point accidentally written undefined into localStorage.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thank you! I use localStorage.remove(), it works well in Chrome too. =D!! You save my day! Thanks again!

Comment: @Dennisboys Great. I added a proper answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022178/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-json

Answer (score 19, accepted):

At some point, something you did corrupted the value of your LocalStorage for that key. LocalStorage can only store strings, so if you pass anything else to it, it will convert it to a string. Since your value is `'undefined'`, that means that at some point, you probably did something like this on accident:

```
var value;
localStorage.setItem('key', value);
```

In this case, `value` is `undefined`, which is not a string. When this gets saved, it will be converted however. Unfortunately, `"undefined"` is not valid JSON. That means that when it tries to parse, it will throw an exception.

To fix your issue, you should clear the bad value out with `removeItem`.

```
localStorage.removeItem("customerDatabase");
```

Comment: But then why was firefox giving a nice string , instead of undefined. This issue appeared in chrome only , no? as mentioned in Question. As Dennisboys has commented on question that on printing only chrome gives undefined.

Comment: @ALBI Since this is using local storage, the value could be from *before* to code looked correct. Perhaps  he was developing in Chrome and at one point had a typo, so Chrome had an incorrect value. BY the time it was loaded in Firefox, the code was correct, so Firefox never got a corrupt storage value.

Answer (score -1):

I had the exact same error while pasting and copying from the Notes app and only then running in Chrome dev tools.

Solved it by replacing the use of Notes app with VScode for temp storage ‍♂️