# Chrome Extension: chrome.storage doesn't save anything

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm about to write an extension for counting my online hours.
The permissions in the manifest.json file:

```
"permissions": [
"tabs",
"<all_urls>",
"storage",
 "cookies"
],
```

background.js:

```
var firstValues = new Array(); //first extension startup values
    firstValues["tag"] = "0";
    firstValues["gesamt"] = "0";


var values = new Array();


chrome.storage.local.get('values', function (result) {
    values = JSON.parse(result.values); //Saving the values in the "values" array
    console.log(values);
    if (!values.length >0) chrome.storage.local.set({'values': JSON.stringify(firstValues)});
}); //Setting values to zero, if it is the first start
```

console.log(values) gives me just a "[]"; the Developer Tool shows nothing in Resources -> Local Storage, neither an error in the console.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: I get error in the BACKGROUND console. It says: SyntaxError: Unexpected token u at... The problem is the result.values undefined. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681366/why-i-always-get-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-from-chrome

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What am I doing wrong?

Several things.

**First,** you are misusing JavaScript arrays. Your `firstValues`, if you log it to console, is `[]` (though it still holds the data). You need an Object to have named keys, Arrays are indexed by numbers.

**Second,** if I try to run that code, I run into the fact that `JSON.parse(undefined)` is an exception (since it's not valid JSON). So you need to either check for that or, even better, do exception handling whenever doing `JSON.parse`.

But even better would be to **not try to serialize things yourself**, as `chrome.storage` docs tell you that it is done automagically. You can store objects and retrieve objects, *unlike `localStorage`*.

So, your code should look something like that:

```
//first extension startup values
var firstValues = { tag : 0, gesamt : 0 }; // Nothing wrong with literals

chrome.storage.local.get('values', function (result) {
    if(result.values) { // defined
        console.log(result.values);
    } else { // uninitialised
        chrome.storage.local.set({values: firstValues});
    }
});
```

Lastly, looking at Resources > Local Storage will not show you the contents of `chrome.storage`, it shows `localStorage`. As far as I am aware, `chrome.storage` is not represented in DevTools.

For convenience, here's a logger for `chrome.storage`:

```
function logStorage() {
    if(chrome.storage) {
        chrome.storage.local.get(function(data){
            console.log("chrome.storage.local:");
            if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
            } else {
                console.log(data);
            }
            chrome.storage.sync.get(function(data){
                console.log("chrome.storage.sync:");
                if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                    console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError);
                } else {
                    console.log(data);
                }
            });
        });
    } else {
        console.warn("chrome.storage is not accessible, check permissions");
    }
}
```