# appcelerator titanium map error

Tags: android, ios, google-maps, appcelerator

I've been tasked with adding a map to my appcelerator project. I have tried the alloy way (since I'm using alloy in the project). That apparently doesn't work and its been suggested that I create the map in the controller. I have done that below and the call to the map is triggered by an onclick function attached to an icon on the primary window. This seems to work on iOS but causes the app  to crash on Android (using a samsung note)

```
function openMap(){
    alert(alertString);
    //var map = Alloy.createController('map');  
    //$.map.show();

    //add alert location here -- get the data from the push message that comes in

    var payload = Ti.App.Properties.getString("latest_buddy_alert","empty");

    if (payload != "empty"){
        var messageDetails = parsePushMessage(payload);
    }

    opera = mapview.createAnnotation({
        latitude: messageDetails['lat'],  // 43.7000,
        longitude: messageDetails['lng'], // 79.4000,
        title: alert,
        pincolor:Map.ANNOTATION_RED,
    });


    var winMap = Titanium.UI.createWindow({  
        title:'Buddy Location',
        BackgroundColor:'#fff'
    });




    var mapview = Titanium.Map.createView({
        mapType: Titanium.Map.STANDARD_TYPE,
        region: {latitude:lat, longitude:lon, latitudeDelta:0.01, longitudeDelta:0.01},
        animate:true,
        regionFit:true,
        userLocation:true
        ,annotations: [opera]
    });
    winMap.add(mapview);
    winMap.open();

    Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
        if (e.error) {
            Ti.API.log('error: ' + JSON.stringify(e.error) );
            return;
        }

        var region = {
                latitude:e.coords.latitude,
                longitude:e.coords.longitude,
                animate:true,
                latitudeDelta:0.04,
                longitudeDelta:0.04
        };                  
        mapview.setLocation(region);
    });
}
```

As mentioned above, this creates an error which crashes the app:

```
Location[1,1] undefined 
uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token u 
source: undefined
```

This is totally unhelpful, since I don't use a token 'u' or variable 'u' anywhere in my code. I have used several variations on the code above, all giving the same error.

I have had some small success moving to a webview, which shows the map on apple, but not on android.

Any ideas?

Comment: does this answer help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14681366/why-i-always-get-uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-from-chrome

Comment: can you try to hard code coordinates inside your `region ` of `mapview `  object, right now i am assuming that `lat` and `lon` are undefined.

Comment: Lat and long are defined and come in thru a push notification