# 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u' when using JSON.parse

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm using JSON.parse as a simple database on my computer with LocalStorage.
It works smoothly until I'm doing the check of this "database";
heres the code for entering information to LocalStorage:

```
var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.registeredUsers);
users.push({username:name, password:userpass, connected:false});
localStorage.registeredUsers = JSON.stringify(users);
```

and when I', having the check of that registeredusers I get the error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u":

```
var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.registeredUsers);
        if(users[userindex].connected)
        {.........}
```

The error points to the line with JSON.parse.
I tried to figure it out with some similiar topics but couldnt find the way.

The code that I push into the array of localstorage:

```
function regBtn(event)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        name=document.forms["regform"]["username"].value;
        userpass=document.forms["regform"]["password"].value;
        localStorage.username=name;
        localStorage.password=userpass;
        if(!(localStorage.registeredUsers))
        {
            localStorage.registeredUsers = '[]';
        }
        var users = JSON.parse(localStorage.registeredUsers);
        users.push({username:name, password:userpass, connected:false});
        localStorage.registeredUsers = JSON.stringify(users);
        $('#mainContent').load('HomePage.html');        
    }
```

Comment: a snippet fom the concrete json would be helpful here...

Comment: Put in a `console.log(localStorage.registeredUsers)` just before the problem line and tell us what you get...

Comment: according to this so-question (http://stackoverflow.com/a/13022566/1776367) `localStorage,registeredUsers` migth be acctually undefined...

Comment: it is undefined, you need to check for `localStorage.registereUsers` before trying to parse it

Comment: I eddited the question and inserted the code where I insert the information into the localstorage

Comment: It can't be empty at that point : if(users[userindex].connected), since you must log in before getting that step

Comment: @Charlie Affumigato You are totally right, it shows undefined for registeredusers, but why is this happening if I did insert information?

Comment: possible duplicate of [uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token U JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022178/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-json)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
var users = localStorage.registeredUsers? JSON.parse(localStorage.registeredUsers) : [];
```

or if you don't like the ternary operator,

```
var users=[];
if(localStorage.registeredUsers){
  users=JSON.parse(localStorage.registeredUsers);
}
```

might help

Answer (score 0):

```
function setCookies(){
        var cookiesObjects = {};
        cookiesObjects.name = document.getElementById('usr').value;
        cookiesObjects.email = document.getElementById('email').value;
        cookiesObjects.age = document.getElementById('age').value;

        var actualString = JSON.stringify(cookiesObjects);


        document.cookie = "user="+ actualString;



    }
    function getCookies(){
        var nameValueArray = document.cookie.split("=");
        var cookieObject = JSON.parse(nameValueArray[1]);
      document.getElementById('usr').value=cookieObject.name;
      document.getElementById('email').value=cookieObject.email;

      document.getElementById('age').value=cookieObject.age;



    }
    function clearCookies(){
        document.getElementById('usr').value= "";
        document.getElementById('email').value= "";
        document.getElementById('age').value= "";
    }
and saying Error : Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

I can't identify the error's cause.