# curl post request to an api was not working using php

Tags: php, curl, push

I am trying to send a push notification using my own API using below code. I am sure curl was enabled in my server. I am getting below as a response.

```
        $url = "http://efpushtest.meteor.com/api/push";

        # Our new data
        $data = json_encode(array(
                'message' => "this is venkat test push message",
                'device' => "12345"
        ));

        $ch = curl_init($url);

        # Setting our options
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

        # Get the response
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
```

Response:

> {"success":false,"message":"Unexpected token u"}

I am not getting where i am going wrong with this code.

Comment: Is the service awaiting for `POST` parameters or `JSON`?

Comment: waiting for post parameters

Answer (score 0):

Since you say in the comment that it is expecting post parameters, your request should not be json encoded as in your code. A proper way to handle that would be to post the fields like so:

```
    $url = "http://efpushtest.meteor.com/api/push";

    # Our new data
    $data = array(
            'message' => "this is venkat test push message",
            'device' => "12345"
    );

    $ch = curl_init($url);

    // build the post string here
    foreach($data as $key=>$value) { 
        $fields_string .= $key.'='.$value.'&'; 
    }

    rtrim($fields_string, '&');

    # Setting our options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, count($data));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    # Get the response
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
```

where you are actually posting the parameters as `POST` parameters passing them in the form a string as you would see in `GET`. Your example would post:

> message=this is venkat test push message&device=12345

If i were you, i would also update the array declaration so it passes `url_encoded` values to the post as in:

```
    $data = array(
            'message' => urlencode("this is venkat test push message"),
            'device' => urlencode("12345")
    );
```

to prevent any special characters in the string to break your requests

*OLD ANSWER FOR JSON*

<del>Try setting the headers of the curl request to specify that you are posting a `json` to the api 

        # Setting our options
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);</del>

Comment: no use i set it up the headers also still same error did u tried

Comment: i tried to test using advanced rest api client(chrome extension) with url and post method. Parameter name data and input as this [{"message": "This is karteek test Push", "device": "1234"}]. It sent push notification successfully. What is meant by that is it json coded data or normal post data

Comment: That's a `json` string but it doesn't say much since it could be the way the chrome extension shows your posted fields. If you have access to the service you could check how it handles the request and post the relevant code here, since from the response you are getting it seems like you are expectig `json` in a python service but we'll need to see how it handles it to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Since I get the same response doing this in the browser console:

`$.post( "/api/push/", { "message" : "this is venkat test push message","device" : "12345" } );`

I would say the problem is in your api code

This answer here seems to say the same thing:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13022566/4152193