# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token only in Wordpress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, cookies

I am making a simple script to write data from an input in cookies, the code works perfectly in a simple HTML: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Loanyut8/),
when i pass the same code to wordpress I get the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u
```

perhaps some basic backend problem however I do not know.

Jquery

```
var cookie = $.cookie('myDemoCookie');
var attrCookie = $.cookie('attrCookie');

// If the cookie has been set in a previous page load, show it in the div directly:
if (cookie) {
    var values = $.parseJSON(cookie);
    var li;
    for (var v in values) {
        li = $('<li><a href="' + values[v] + '">' + values[v] + '</a></li>');

        $('.jq-text').append(li).show();
    }
}

$('.fields a').click(function(e) {
    var text = $('#inputBox').val();
    var values = $.parseJSON($.cookie('myDemoCookie'));
    if (!values) {
        values = [];
    }
    values.push(text);
    console.log(values);
    // Setting a cookie with a seven day validity:
    $.cookie('myDemoCookie', JSON.stringify(values), {
        expires: 7,
        path: '/'
    });


    $(".jq-text").append('<li><a href="' + text + '">' + text + '</a></li>');

    e.preventDefault();

});

$('#form1').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
})
```

Comment: In wich Line does the Error occurs?

Comment: [link](https://s3.amazonaws.com/fvd-data/notes/264643/1422404592-f9NDgb/screen.png)

Comment: I can't see any `u` Token

Comment: The code you've supplied doesn't contain the token `u` - the error must be somewhere else. Try searching your codebase for this token. I'd use a regex search: `\bu\b`

Comment: I think you're getting an error when you set the variable 'values' because 'myDemoCookie' is undefined. Try wrapping that in a check to make sure it's not undefined before setting it. This question has an answer and some comments that may better explain the issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022178/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-json