# Ajax call to Web API not parsing JSON properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a Web API application that is set to respond to the GET verb with a string. When I test this in the browser I can see my JSON. I have validated my JSON response using a validation tool. The JSON is below. The issue seems to start when I try using a JQuery AJAX call to retrieve the data. I receive an error in the console stating

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

I know my service is responding with valid JSON so it must be an issue with my AJAX call (see below). My guess is that it is unable to parse because the object is undefined, however; I don't know why it is undefined. Does anyone have any thoughts?

JSON

```
[{
    "ID": 330,
    "type": "ctest2",
    "subSystem": "sub tests",
    "SubSystemComponent": "some syb system comp",
    "subSystemId": 1234,
    "eventCategory": "my category",
    "eventName": "my event name",
    "subEvent": "my sub event",
    "userDef1": "user def 1",
    "timestamp": "2008-07-22T12:11:04",
    "senderId": "43zzz",
    "receiverId": "64",
    "senderName": "Chris",
    "originalFileLocation": "C:\\temp\\",
    "fileSize": 1234567890,
    "recordCount": 84,
    "gs808": "",
    "st01": "st01 stuff",
    "transCount": 90210,
    "ReceiverName": null,
    "SourceSystem": null
}, {
    "ID": 329,
    "type": "ctest2",
    "subSystem": "sub tests",
    "SubSystemComponent": "some syb system comp",
    "subSystemId": 1234,
    "eventCategory": "my category",
    "eventName": "my event name",
    "subEvent": "my sub event",
    "userDef1": "user def 1",
    "timestamp": "2008-07-22T12:11:04",
    "senderId": "43zzz",
    "receiverId": "64",
    "senderName": "Chris",
    "originalFileLocation": "C:\\temp\\",
    "fileSize": 1234567890,
    "recordCount": 84,
    "gs808": "",
    "st01": "st01 stuff",
    "transCount": 90210,
    "ReceiverName": null,
    "SourceSystem": null
}]
```

AJAX

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "{URL}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    beforeSend: function (request) { request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*') },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (msg) {
        var data = $.parseJSON(msg.d);

        $.each(data, function (index, value) {
            console.log('record number ' + index + ' - value - ' + value);
        });
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error) {
        var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
        alert(err.Message);
    },
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token U JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022178/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-json)

Comment: Why do you have msg.d in your code? Can you do a console.log there? Will help you out.

Comment: There is no property `d` in your data and no need to use `$.parseJSON`. Try `$.each(msg, func....`

Comment: $.parseJSON is reundant because you specified `dataType: "json"` already, btw. Also it expects a string and you're going to be giving it an object (if msg.d actually existed, which it doesn't). Makes no sense

Comment: `request.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')` also makes no sense. Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a _response_ header. It's only valid in a response. Sending it in the _request_, as you're doing, achieves nothing. The server will just ignore it.

Comment: And why the use of `eval(` (yuk)??? If the error response is JSON just use xhr.responseJSON directly, or do JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).

Comment: @charlietfl . When I change that code I get the below in the console. record number 0 - value - [object Object].

Comment: @ChrisLombardi that's because `value`, when used as per Charlie's example, is an object - it represents one of the items your JSON array, e.g. `{
    "ID": 330,
    "type": "ctest2",
    "subSystem": "sub tests"`...etc etc. So you can't just print out a whole object (well, you can, if you do `JSON.stringify(value)` but you just get back the JSON you put in). Did you want a specific property or properties from the object? To display it in a certain format? What's your goal?

Comment: @ADyson I am trying to retrieve the JSON from the API and then use it in a local variable to reference later.

Comment: well `msg` is already a local variable containing all the JSON. So if that's all you want, then your job is more or less done, you just maybe need to assign it to a global variable which can be accessed outside the "success" function? Or trigger another function to do something with the data?

Comment: I assigned it to a local global variable and it worked like a charm with my table. Thank you!

Comment: Regardless of whatever other problems your code might have, if the server  you’re making the request to isn’t CORS-enabled, then your browser will block your frontend code from access to the response. As far as what you need to do to CORS-enable the server: For one thing, the request in your code triggers your browsers to do a CORS preflight OPTIONS request before attempting the GET request from you code. So, unless your server is responding to that preflight OPTIONS request in the right way, nothing else in your frontend code after that is going to work as expected.