# How to use json in handlebars with nodeJs expressJs

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, express, handlebars.js

I have a JSON data in dataList variable and I want to add this in custom handlebars helper as a parameter.

```
var dataList = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Arrange meeting",
    "date": "Today 10:35 | By Admin",
    "completed": true
  },
];
```

Handlebars Custom helper

```
var Handlebar = require('handlebars');
Handlebar.registerHelper('List', function(data, options){
  //console.log(data) //returns undefined 
  return options.fn(JSON.parse(data)); // gives error
});
```

Custom Helper Rendering:

```
{{#List dataList}} 
  {{> widgets/toDoList}}
{{/List}}
```

It produce error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

Whereas, it is working with the static data

```
{{#List '[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Arrange meeting",
    "date": "Today 10:35 | By Admin",
    "completed": true
  },
]' }} 
  {{> widgets/toDoList}}
{{/List}}
```

Comment: `When I have add full json code in {{#List full_json_code_here}} with single quotes then works perfectly` can you please explain it ? or better add the use case in the question, when its working

Comment: @RaghavGarg Qus. updated.

Comment: thanks for the update, I am pretty much sure, it's not the problem of custom helper, but the way you are passing data to it. Please also show where you are calling this view.!! If you are using express, it would be like `res.render('view-name', data)`.

Comment: Thankyou!!  @RaghavGarg it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am pretty much sure, it's not the problem of custom helper, but the way you are passing data to it.

If you are using express, it would be like `res.render('view-name', data)`

Answer (score 0):

it's becuase your `data` return `undefined`
see for more here [ [uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token U JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022178/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-json) ]

Comment: JSON dataList is already defined but still not getting the actual issue.

Comment: ```Handlebar.registerHelper('List', function(data, options){
    //console.log(data) //returns undefined 
    return options.fn(JSON.parse(data));
});``` in this code you have done parsing into json but due to undefined data you got this error.

Comment: Okay!! So can you explain me how to define dataList?? in  {{#List dataList }} 
         {{> widgets/toDoList}}
    {{/List}}

Comment: have you ever play with handlebar???? here tutorial for that (video)[https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HuAnM6b2d8]

Comment: @JigneshSanghani , why have you put the question as the answer just reframed? OP told us that the data is `undefined` and hence the error. Please help in identifying why is it coming `undefined`..!!

Answer (score 0):

JSON.parse accepts a string, but you pass him an array