# ajax post 500 internal server error using Node and Nginx

Tags: node.js, ajax

I'm trying to post to my node server but I get a "Failed to load resource" 500 Internal Server Error code and I can't figure out why.

Here is the [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ayLSp.png) on what Node says.

My server code:

```
var db     = null
var app = null
//console.error(config.mongohq)
mongo.init(
  {
    name:     config.mongohq.name,
    host:     config.mongohq.host,
    port:     config.mongohq.port,
    username: config.mongohq.username,
    password: config.mongohq.password,
  },
  function(res){
    db = res
    var prefix = '/assignment2/'
    app = express()
    // Configuration
     app.use(bodyParser.json()); // for parsing application/json
     app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // for parsing

     //multer_upload = multer({ dest: './images' }).any();

    app.get(prefix + 'search/:query', search);
    app.post(prefix + ":chicken/log", log)

    app.listen(3009)
    console.error('Server listening on port 3009')
  },
  function(err){
    console.error(err)
  }
)

function log(req,res)
{
      var list = JSON.parse(req.body.items);
      console.log(hello)
      for (var i = 0; i <list.length; i++)
      {
        fs.appendFile("assignment2/Foghorn/log.dat", JSON.stringify(list[i]));
      }
}
```

My client side post code:

```
//Clear the local storage and array of the user's choice of chicken type


var server = "http://xxxx:xxxx/assignment2/";
function sendLogs()
{
        clearFields();
        var path;

        if(chickenNumber == 0)
        {
          var items = {logs: foghorn_items};
          path = server + "Foghorn/log";
          $.ajax({
          url: path,
          method: 'POST',
          dataType: 'JSON',
          data: items,
          success: function (data){
            alert('Logs sent to file');
          }
          });

    //      foghorn_items.length = 0;
    //      localStorage.removeItem("foghorn_items");

}
```

Hid my ip and port for security reasons.

I'm pretty sure my log.dat file is in assignment2/Foghorn in the html folder of my Nginx

According to node, the error is pointing at the 1st line in the log() method

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [uncaught syntaxerror unexpected token U JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022178/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The offending line in your code is `var list = JSON.parse(req.body.items)`.

But `req.body.items` isn't a text string, it's an object with body parameters in it. So, of course JSON.parse rejects it.

The JSON parser middleware (`app.use(bodyParser.json())`) parses the JSON in your request and puts the result at `req.body`. So, you don't need to parse it again.

Comment: Oh I see. I'm new to this so I didn't realise it. I will try your suggestion

Comment: Don't know why you got downvoted but this solved my problem.

Comment: Some people downvote questions and answers when they already know the answers and believe they are obvious.Don't worry about downvotes.