# How to solve fetch return Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0 at parse (<anonymous>) react native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to make authentication in react native app using auth0, I have form with username and password with submit button, I have three fetches api, the first fetch authenticate user name, password and system token(stored in params) to get the token of user.

The second fetch uses the obtained token in previous fetch to get user id and the third fetch uses the obtained userid in previous fetch to get user meta_data.

```
submit = () => {
    const bodyParams = {
      client_id: params.clientId,
      grant_type: 'password',
       username: this.state.email,
       password: this.state.password,
      audience: params.apiAudience,
      scope: params.scope
    };

//First fetch : authenticate with user name, password, ... to get the token of user
    fetch(`https://${params.domain}/oauth/token`, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Authorization':params.accesstoken,
          'Accept': 'application/json',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(bodyParams)
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {  
console.log(responseJson); //{access_token: "token", id_token: "id-token", scope: "openid profile email address phone read:current_us…device_credentials update:current_user_identities", expires_in: 86400, token_type: "Bearer"}
          if (responseJson.error) {
            Alert.alert(responseJson.error_description);
          }
global.access_token=responseJson.access_token;
       AsyncStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(global.access_token));
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });

//Second fetch : use the obtained token in previous fetch to get user id 
    fetch(`https://${params.domain}/userinfo`, {
      method: 'GET',
      headers: {
        'Authorization':"Bearer "+global.access_token,
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
console.log(responseJson); //SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0 at parse (<anonymous>)

          global.userid = responseJson.sub;
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });


//Third fetch : use the obtained userid in previous fetch to get user meta_data 
      fetch(`https://${params.domain}/api/v2/users/${global.userid}`, {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
 'Authorization':`Bearer ${global.access_token}`,
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }
      })
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then(responseJson => {
var access =responseJson.user_metadata.entitlements.tageblatt.includes("web-access"):;
if(access){
  this.props.navigation.navigate('Feed',{ HaveAccess:access , tokeeeen:params1.usertoken
   })
}
 else{
       Alert.alert("wrong not autroized");
 }
        }

      )
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        });

}
```

If I click submit button first time I have:

`console.log(responseJson)` in first fetch always works and give the required token for user.

`console.log(responseJson)` in second fetch gives  `SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0 at parse (<anonymous>)`

`console.log(responseJson)` in third fetch gives  `{statusCode: 400, error: "Bad Request", message: "Bad HTTP authentication header format", errorCode: "Bearer"}`

If I click submit button multiple times it works fine and gives

`console.log(responseJson)` in second fetch gives `{sub: "auth0|userid", nickname: "tarifaljnidi1985".......`

`console.log(responseJson)` in third fetch gives  `{created_at: "2020-05-27T09:42:09.844Z", email: "someemail@hotmail.com", email_verified: true, identities: Array(1), name: "someemail@hotmail.com", …`

And sometimes it works fine from the first click.

The syntax error:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0
    at parse (<anonymous>)
    at tryCallOne (C:\project\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37)
    at C:\project\node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:123
    at C:\project\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:277
    at _callTimer (C:\project\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:135)
    at _callImmediatesPass (C:\project\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:183)
    at Object.callImmediates (C:\project\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Core\Timers\JSTimers.js:446)
    at MessageQueue.__callImmediates (C:\\project\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:396)
    at C:\project\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:144
    at MessageQueue.__guard (C:\project\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\BatchedBridge\MessageQueue.js:373)
```

Comment: Put the `console.log` before the `response.json()` so that you can see what the response is before you get the error. The server is likely returning an error message instead of JSON.

Comment: [It's not JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022178/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-json)

Comment: second console Response {type: "default", status: 401, ok: false, statusText: undefined, headers: Headers, …}TypeError: Cannot read property 'sub' of undefined

Comment: third console Response {type: "default", status: 400, ok: false, statusText: undefined, headers: Headers, …}
TypeError: Cannot read property 'user_metadata' of undefined

Comment: sub is user id in second