# How can I get the key values from API props response

Tags: node.js, next.js, coingecko

I couldn't map the second API response https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/global with error prompted *(read property 'map' of undefined)*, while the first API is fine.
Whats the issue here?

```
export default function Home(props) {
  const { data } = props.result;
  const { global } = props.nextResult;

      <table className="table2 table-hover table-dark">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Markets</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {global.map (gg => (
            <tr key={gg.endedicos}>
              <td>{gg.markets}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
  const params = {
    order: CoinGecko.ORDER.MARKET_CAP_DESC
  };
  const [result, nextResult] = await Promise.all([
    coinGeckoClient.coins.markets({params}), 
    coinGeckoClient.global()
  ]);
  return {
    props: {
      result, nextResult
    },
  }
}
```

Comment: The error tells you that `global` is undefined. If you log `nextResult` to the console inside `getServerSideProps`, do you get the expected output?

Comment: nope, i got error from the log returned. But with direct http https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/global , result is fine. Weird..

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Error `Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0`

Comment: Have a look at [Uncaught syntax error unexpected token u JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022178/uncaught-syntaxerror-unexpected-token-u-json). Something's wrong with the request/response.